# Formatting JSON GET results in Python

Tags: python, json, europepmc

I am trying to get Covid-19 JSON data from [Europe Pubmed Central](http://europepmc.org/). The JSON results returned by Europe PMC server looks like [this](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=(%E2%80%9C2019-nCoV%E2%80%9D)&format=json).

My initial code querying the server looks like this:

```
import requests
import json


mydata = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=(%E2%80%9C2019-nCoV%E2%80%9D)&format=json"

#get Server response
reply = requests.get(mydata)

#print out results
print(reply.json())
```

I wish to get rid of these part of the JSON:

```
{'version': '6.2', 'hitCount': 847, 'nextCursorMark': 'AoIIQVJxdCg0MTI2NjU3Mw==', 'request': {'queryString': '(“2019-nCoV”)', 'resultType': 'lite', 'cursorMark': '*', 'pageSize': 25, 'sort': '', 'synonym': False}, 'resultList':
```

How can i get rid of this part in python? I apologize in advance for the long url querystring.

Comment: There's a lot that doesn't add up here. Firstly; are you sure you really need that query string? Can the API not be accessed in a more efficient way? Secondly, that query string is what you _send_ to the server - not what you need to process. Thirdly, you haven't shown the response that you're trying to parse into that dictionary

Comment: I have just edited the question with a shorter querystring and also provided a link of the results that i wish to format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend simply doing

```
reply = reply['resultList']
```

Then reply would consist only of

```
{
"result": [
  {
    "id": "32036774",
    "source": "MED",
    "pmid": "32036774",
    "pmcid": "PMC7054940",
    "doi": "10.1080/01652176.2020.1727993",
    "title": "Emerging novel coronavirus (2019-nCoV)-current scenario, evolutionary perspective based on genome analysis and recent developments.",
    "authorString": "Malik YS, Sircar S, Bhat S, Sharun K, Dhama K, Dadar M, Tiwari R, Chaicumpa W.",
    "journalTitle": "Vet Q",
    "issue": "1",
    "journalVolume": "40",
    "pubYear": "2020",
    "journalIssn": "0165-2176; 1875-5941; ",
    "pageInfo": "68-76",
    "pubType": "other; review; journal article",
    "isOpenAccess": "Y",
    "inEPMC": "Y",
    "inPMC": "N",
    "hasPDF": "Y",
    "hasBook": "N",
    "hasSuppl": "Y",
    "citedByCount": 0,
    "hasReferences": "N",
    "hasTextMinedTerms": "Y",
    "hasDbCrossReferences": "N",
    "hasLabsLinks": "Y",
    "hasTMAccessionNumbers": "Y",
    "tmAccessionTypeList": {
      "accessionType": [
        "gen"
      ]
    },
    "firstIndexDate": "2020-02-11",
    "firstPublicationDate": "2020-12-01"
  }, ...
  ]
}
```

From there you could iterate over all object like so

```
for result in reply['results']:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please expound further @DavidTeather

Comment: I have actually figured your answer out. Thank you.